# local Airflow install & setup: failing at `airflow db init` with `ValueError: No such constraint: 'dag_tag__fkey'`

Tags: python, airflow, alembic

I'm trying to install airflow 2.6 following the quick start guide [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start.html).

Installation appears to work fine following the guide above.

But when I get to the setup part, specifically the `airflow standalone` or `airflow db init` commands, I get the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/airflow_3_7_2023/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/operations/batch.py", line 700, in drop_constraint
    raise ValueError("No such constraint: '%s'" % const.name)
ValueError: No such constraint: 'dag_tag__fkey'
```

Seems to be something with the alembic package?. The airflow installation also installed alembic. Should I uninstall alembic and try different versions?

I've tried airflow install and setup in python 3.7 and 3.8 envs and gotten the same error in each. I'm on mac Ventura 13.2.1

Any ideas are appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For me helped restarting the airflow db

```
airflow db reset
```

After that you can init your db by

```
airflow db init
```

Hope it will helps